# iPhone X constantly pocket dialling (et al)

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone X running iOS 12.1.2.

I find when I pull it from my shirt pocket it has often been "working" itself, I will be in some random app. Sometimes that results in a pocket dial or FT call, sometimes I'm in Messages with gibberish typed in, etc.

FaceId is turned on and the screen lights up when I look at it, so why is it going active in my pocket? Is there any way to stop this? It's very annoying.

Comment: If you're going to mention the iOS version number, consider that this question will appear on Ask Different for years, and *if* the version is somehow significant then "lates (auto-update)" won't be of any help to future readers.

Comment: Do you have Raise to Wake turned on?  What do you have Auto-Lock set to?

Comment: Auto-lock is 30 seconds. Raise-to-wake is on. But I'm not raising it in my pocket.

Comment: I understand you're not raising it in your pocket.  I've had the same experience as you when I had that setting turned on.  My guess is it would interpret movement in the pocket (soon after I used the iPhone) as still being in use and wake-up the screen.  Try turning it off and see if that helps.  Also turn off Tap to Wake if it's on.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case this is a help to any future readers, I found the reason for my iPhone XS constantly pocket dialling being emergency contacts. When FaceID fails in my pocket, it manages to tap emergency and then either dial a random number or go into my Medical ID and call one of my emergency contacts.

Turning off emergency contacts has almost completely solved the problem, the only other problem being raise-to-wake which commonly activates in my pocket. I used a OnePlus before this (which sucked), but it did have this awesome feature called Pocket Mode which prevented the screen activating in my pocket - which I do miss.